# Are CSS Generated Content acceptable in terms of SEO?

Tags: css, seo

I run an online literary journal which leads to an indexing problem--our content is not "about" literature -- it **is** literature. As such, Google is really bad at identifying what's going on, and due to the very low keyword density we have to try and work with, I've been looking for ways to slash interface text and turn it into iconography where possible.

I've been looking for a way to do the same with our post dates, but it's been a long search. I stumbled across the idea of using CSS generated content `content:attr(id)` to substitute the ID attribute of an invisible image into the page itself.

This works on the display level, however, I haven't been able to track down anything conclusive on whether this interface-only text will still get indexed, or whether we'll be able to move away from months and days of the week being our most-frequent keywords. I know Google will still see it; anyone know if it'll "count"?

Comment: I can't answer your question in a definitive way, but my gut feeling is this will not be read correctly by search engines. But it sounds like a bad solution anyway - the SEO problem should be tackled otherwise, I'm having a hard time seeing how post dates could seriously interfere with search engine results

Comment: Of our top 40 keywords in Webmaster Tools, 1 is our journal's name, 10 are actual keywords, and 29 are interface words.  To drill down further, of the 29, 9 are months, 6 are days of the week or month, and most of the remainder are other menu/interface items (RSS, ISSN, share, facebook, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the 'best' way to ensure something is hidden from a search engine is to either load it via AJAX or (shudder) include it with flash.

If you feel that the non-content aspects of your site are adversely affecting your site's standing in the various search engines, you could load these elements via AJAX.

Only if you really think these elements are seriously affecting your position.

Below is an image describing areas of this page that one could conceivably post-load via AJAX, if one was overly concerned about their impact on SEO:

[image: Example of areas on this page that could be loaded via AJAX]

I know this doesn't specifically answer your question, it's a suggestion for an alternative way to tackle your issue.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. We're trying to (and have, thus far) keep JS off of the main site (though it is unavoidable on our blog,) but we may ultimately have to throw in the towel and go with AJAX.

Comment: Yeah, the navigation really shouldn't be loaded with AJAX... Thought it wouldn't remove the offending elements from the page's structure, have you tried moving them further down in the page's structure, so the search engines don't hit it so near the top of the document? With one site I made I improved results by putting the toolbar ( which has a lot of nav links ) at the bottom of the doc's structure, and moving it to the top with CSS.

Comment: Sorry--was out for a conference. Yes, the navigation/copyright etc. all appear last in the code, but some of the interface text (post dates, etc.) that is causing problems is harder to separate. In the new redesign we're basically moving the nav to image sprites to keep that information out of the page. We've also cut ourselves down from 10 posts per page to 1, to hopefully increase the density a little (though we're going to be watching to see if we get penalized for having subscription information on each post page since the ratio of duplicate content will also be changed drastically).